# Django value to an HTML TextArea via Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, textarea

first, I will like to apologize for my english, because it's not my native language :( 
So... I'm using Django for web development and I've being facing an issue, the thing is that I currently have this model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_notes = models.TextField(default="")
```

And I want to show project_notes data in a HTML TextArea, so for doing this, I have been using Javascript in the following way:

```
<script>
  var notes = "{{ proyecto.project_notes | safe }}";
  document.getElementById("notesTextArea").value = notes;
</script>
```

Note that notesTextArea is the id for the textarea tag on my html, and this script is right on the bottom of my html document (before body tag's end)

And I'm rendering this template (and also saving changes in case of POST request) with this python function on my views.py:

```
def notas(request, id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request=request, template_name="tasks/notes.html", context={"proyecto": project})
    else:
        new_notes = request.POST["notes"]
        project.project_notes = new_notes
        project.save()
        return redirect('tasks:notas', id=id)
```

The issue is that when I add a newline on the text area (press intro) and save the data, apparently the data is saving (because I checked django admin) but the textarea is no longer showing the data. Apparently is an issue with breaklines so I tried to use:

```
{{ proyecto.project_notes | linebreaks }}
```

But it shows me 
 tags on my textarea and when I try to replace the tags via javascript, again, the textarea shows me no data.
Note that I call my python variable with double quote because javascript sent me an error when I didn't (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)

Can anyone help me with this? What am I doing wrong?
Also, I want to comment that I have started to work recently in software development so you may find that there are better ways to do some things that I have done here (feel free to comment), also, this is a personal web application to manage my current projects.

I will also add some pictures with my current template view (and django admin info)

[Django-admin (with | safe )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHTwA.png)

[What text area is showing with | safe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXowi.png)

[What text area shows with | linebreaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsv5u.png)

Thanks!!!

**UPDATE**
How am I assigning textArea's value? This way:

```
<script> var notes = "{{ proyecto.project_notes | linebreaks }}"; document.getElementById("notesTextArea").value = notes; 
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure of the mechanism you are using but are you sure that your javascript runs the second time when your form is loaded?
I could help if I knew a few more details. 
(Also, your English is not that bad. have a great day!)

Comment: Thanks! Well my javascript is getting the data from the database (I checked with console.log) but textArea is not showing this when I use "| safe".  I'm returning the data through render to my template and then on my template I'm assigning textArea's value with this code: <script>
  var notes = "{{ proyecto.project_notes | linebreaks }}";
  document.getElementById("notesTextArea").value = notes;
</script> (for the moment I'm using linebreaks that at least show me the content of the data, but it shows with html tags, when I remove this html tags using "safe" it shows nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```js
document.getElementById("notesTextArea").append(
    "{{ proyecto.project_notes | linebreaks }}"
)
```

It works for `textarea` element.